# npm install hangs at kerberos or bson

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

Not sure if this is because I'm connected to China net (not Internet but fire walled China provide sorry excuse for an Internet) or because npm has problems but I can't seem to install things with npm.

Tried

Gets me to

```
npm info install kerberos@0.0.3

> kerberos@0.0.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

Sometimes it goes through after a very long time of no update at all (with the --verbose option) but then gets to

```
npm info postinstall mquery@0.8.0

> bson@0.2.12 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

Maybe I'm too impatient to just kill the process after 2 hours but it looks like something just hangs without telling me because when it is successful the whole thing takes less than 20 minutes. The last time it worked was about 2 weeks ago though.

Trying to do a npm install on a package that has a mongoose dependency but that dependency can never be fulfilled. My colleague advised me to do npm install to get all the updated packages (included the most recent they worked on) but every time someone tells me that I'm looking at one of the two mentioned above messages for the rest of the day and sometimes the next day as well.

Will try a npm install -g mongoose over night and hope an npm link will work (not trying to download and install something that just gets stuck for hours).

Anyone else in China finding it near to impossible to use npm (depending on the firewall's mood)?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and had a look at the builderror.log file. The file is located in the corresponding node module folder. In your case it is either

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/builderror.log

or

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/builderror.log

If you started npm with `-dd` you can see the status of gyp inside of this file and maybe can also spot some permission problems or similar.

This is what I did to fix it:

1. Remove all currently installed header files with `rm ~/.node-gyp/`
2. install node-gyp globally with `npm install -g node-gyp`
3. call node-gyp to install header files `node-gyp install` (installs headers for the current node version).
4. remove node-gyp again `npm uninstall -g node-gyp` (optional)

Afterwards the simple `npm install` for my project ran through in just some seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It looks more like your compile is taking a long time than your install.  (node-gyp invokes the C++ compiler to build native-code addons)

It may be that you lack some of the parts (libraries, compilers) needed to build native add-ons.  I can't help you figure out what without asking you a few more questions, though:

Did you install node from source or from a package?
Are `python` and a C/C++ compiler installed?
Can you run `npm` with two `-d` flags to increase the verbosity (`npm -dd install kerberos`) and post the resulting npm-debug.log to https://gist.github.com to help with debugging?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I install it on a Mac and when it is successful it does it within 5 minutes. When it's not it just hangs and doesn't do anything. Longest record of it staying there without any output is 2 hours. I suspect unhanded exception due to bad connection. Not sure if a network connection is needed during compile time.

Comment: A network connection is needed to install the libraries just *before* the compilation.

You can ensure that node-gyp has up-to-date files by running 
```$(dirname `which npm`)/../lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp install```